# Idiomatic word counting in Rust

Tags: regex, file, hash-map, rust

My goal is to read from standard input, break up the input into words, case-insensitively, and produce a report to standard output, where each line is a word followed by a space followed by its count. The output should be sorted by words.

This is my code:

```
use std::collections::BTreeMap;
use std::io;
use std::io::BufRead;

fn main() {
    let mut counts: BTreeMap<String, isize> = BTreeMap::new();
    let stdin = io::stdin();
    for line_result in stdin.lock().lines() {
        match line_result {
            Ok(line) => {
                let lowercase_line = line.to_lowercase();
                let words = lowercase_line.split(|c: char| {
                     !(c.is_alphabetic() || c == '\'')
                 }).filter(|s| !s.is_empty());
                 for word in words {
                    *(counts.entry(word.to_string()).or_insert(0)) += 1;
                 }
            },
            Err(e) => {
                panic!("Error parsing stdin: {:?}", e);
            }
        }
    }
    for (key, value) in counts.iter() {
        println!("{} {}", key, value);
    }
}
```

My questions are:

- Is `BTree` the proper dictionary?
- I know that there is a regex crate, but I would like to stay with things in standard Rust. That said, splitting is a terrible way to break up lines because you have to filter empties. Is there a way to just match the words, rather than splitting on non-word sequences?
- Is matching on the `Err` part of the result proper? Or should we let the script crash? Is panicking okay?
- I noticed one is not allowed to say `let words = line.to_lowercase().split(...) because of the infamous`"borrowed reference does not live long enough"` but is there a cleaner way?
- Is there a nicer way to count words in a map? I don't like the asterisk.
- I wish I didn't have to do an explicit lock on stdin.

Rust has a lot of things going for it, but when I compare what I got to the much prettier Julia version of this script, namely...

```
counts = Dict{AbstractString, UInt64}()
for line in eachline(STDIN)
  for word in matchall(r"[a-z\']+", lowercase(line))
    counts[word] = get(counts, word, 0) + 1
  end
end
for (word, count) in sort(collect(counts))
  println("$word $count")
end
```

...I'm thinking I don't know Rust very well, *or*, that's just the way things are. I mean, I know as a systems language, it's really hard to make vectors and strings. And they tell me I will learn to love the borrow checker. :) Hopefully someone with expertise in idiomatic Rust can be of service here. I'm not expecting it to be as short as the Julia code but I do fear my Rust is not idiomatic enough.

Comment: Not that I'm too familiar with Rust, but it would appear the only two data structures for dictionaries are `HashMap` and `BTreeMap`. In the Julia example you clearly want to have the stuff sorted which is guaranteed with the `BTreeMap` and NOT the `HashMap`. So in this case I would argue that `BTreeMap` is the "proper dictionary".

Comment: Good to know -- all I could find in the world of sorted maps was `BTreeMap`, but thought there might be something else, specific to counters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no "proper" dictionary, there are just different trade-offs. In this case, we have that `HashMap` gives us better asymptotic random access whereas `BTreeMap` gives us sortedness.

Sorting the a `HashMap` after-the-fact is well and good, but `BTreeMap` is already sorted so it seems like the better choice.

Rust very heavily gives tasks out to crates. This is guided by [RFC 1242](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/1242-rust-lang-crates.md), and you might notice [`regex` is in rust-lang-nursery](https://github.com/rust-lang-nursery/regex). This means it *is* official and it is "standard rust"; it's just not in the standard library.

Plus, it's as easy as adding `regex = "0.1"` to your `Cargo.toml`, so that's no reason to avoid it.

Ignoring that, that

```
let words = line.to_lowercase().split(...)
```

doesn't work is just a fact of life right now, although that *will* eventually get fixed with non-lexical lifetimes.

These imports

```
use std::io;
use std::io::BufRead;
```

are nicer as

```
use std::io::{self, BufRead};
```

The large `match`

```
match line_result {
    Ok(line) => {
        ...
    },
    Err(e) => {
        panic!("Error parsing stdin: {:?}", e);
    }
}
```

would be nicer as

```
let line = match line_result {
    Ok(line) => line,
    Err(e) => panic!("Error parsing stdin: {:?}", e),
};

...
```

or even

```
let line = line_result.unwrap_or_else(
    |e| panic!("Error parsing stdin: {:?}", e)
);
```

But in this case the error handling doesn't add anything, so I'd just `unwrap`. All of these examples panic; a method that doesn't would involve error handling by printing and then returning from the function. Printing is normally worse to debug (no tracebacks) but nicer for end-users.

Instead of

```
*(counts.entry(word.to_string()).or_insert(0)) += 1;
```

which always allocates a new `String`, one can index with a borrowed `&str`. Sadly [this isn't supported by the `entry` API right now](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/19986#issuecomment-91274821), but you can hack around it:

```
if let Some(count) = counts.get_mut(word) {
    *count += 1;
    continue;
}
counts.insert(word.into(), 1);
```

Note the use of `if let`/`continue` instead of `match` is because of lexical lifetimes.

Since this is currently pretty ugly and the speedup probably doesn't matter, I'll leave this as a hypothetical. You say you "don't like the asterisk", but that's kind'a how it's meant to be done. I guess you could go the Julia route (`get` + `unwrap_or` + `insert`), but that's not really better.

After a few miscellaneous changes, the code for me looks like

```
extern crate regex;

use std::collections::BTreeMap;
use std::io::{self, BufRead};

use regex::Regex;

fn main() {
    let word_re = Regex::new(r"[a-z']+").unwrap();

    let mut counts: BTreeMap<String, isize> = BTreeMap::new();

    let stdin = io::stdin();
    for line in stdin.lock().lines() {
        let line = line.unwrap().to_lowercase();
        let matches = word_re.find_iter(&line);
        let words = matches.map(|(x, y)| &line[x..y]);

        for word in words {
            *counts.entry(word.into()).or_insert(0) += 1;
        }
    }
    for (key, value) in counts.iter() {
        println!("{} {}", key, value);
    }
}
```

This isn't as nice as the Julia code, but it's giving you a lot of opportunities to be a lot more efficient, and it's catching a lot more errors. It's true that locking `stdin` feels like a chore on 50-line examples, but it fits Rust's macro-goals of faster, safer APIs.

Comment: This was fantastic and full of a lot of great information. I like _all_ the suggestions and am looking forward to non-lexical lifetimes. I guess I can learn to like the `*`, after all systems programming in Rust is about knowing what's allocated when and where, etc. My goal is to ramp up writing idiomatic Rust. This helps.

Answer (score 3):

Your question is remarkably similar to this [recent Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36967681/155423), so I'd borrow the core solution and build on top of [Veedrac's answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/127364/32521).

Additionally...

1. Use `expect` instead of `unwrap`. This allows you to add a bit of human-readable (and programmer-findable) text for when (not if) an error occurs. `expect` completely replaces your `match` and `panic!` on `Err`.
2. `key` and `value` are too generic names for this case. Give them better names like the Julia code.
3. I try very hard to avoid explicit type specifications when they can be inferred. In this case, there's no need to specify the type of `counts`. Type inference will see that the key is a `String`. If you didn't specify a type for the numeric literal, `i32` will be used by default. If you *do* need a specific size integer, you can add the type to the literal.
4. Using a signed integer for the count is strange; you can't have -5 words. An unsigned type is better.

---

```
use std::collections::BTreeMap;
use std::io::{self, BufRead};

fn main() {
    let mut counts = BTreeMap::new();

    let stdin = io::stdin();
    for line in stdin.lock().lines() {
        let line = line.expect("Error parsing stdin");

        for word in line.split_whitespace().map(str::to_lowercase) {
            *counts.entry(word).or_insert(0usize) += 1;
        }
    }

    for (word, count) in counts.iter() {
        println!("{} {}", word, count);
    }
}
```

> I wish I didn't have to do an explicit lock on stdin.

I'd be very curious to know what would happen with the Julia code if you ran the code that reads from standard in with multiple threads.

---

As [pointed out by Veedrac](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/127350/idiomatic-word-counting-in-rust#comment238136_127381), splitting on whitespace would not be the exact same behavior. In that spirit, here's another solution that's not exactly the same. We rely on the regex engine to do case folding instead of the standard library!

```
extern crate regex;

use std::collections::BTreeMap;
use std::io::{self, BufRead};
use regex::Regex;

fn main() {
    let mut counts = BTreeMap::new();

    let word_regex = Regex::new(r"(?i)[a-z']+").expect("Could not compile regex");

    let stdin = io::stdin();
    for line in stdin.lock().lines() {
        let line = line.expect("Error parsing stdin");
        let words = word_regex.find_iter(&line).map(|(s, e)| &line[s..e]);
        for word in words.map(str::to_lowercase) {
            *counts.entry(word).or_insert(0usize) += 1;
        }
    }

    for (word, count) in counts.iter() {
        println!("{} {}", word, count);
    }
}
```

You could also use a character class (`r"[[:alpha:]']+"`) if you only care about ASCII letters. You could use `[:word:]` for "word character" as well.

Comment: The change to `split_whitespace` doesn't seem particularly semantics-preserving.

Comment: Also IMO annotating the `0` with the type rather than the `counts` variable seems much more forceful about avoiding annotations than I would be. It seems more fragile, so to say.

Comment: @Veedrac good point about the change in semantics! I was making a bit of a leap as *usually* people think of words as "things separated by spaces". I have experience with tokenization in a few languages that don't use spaces at all, but folk tend to get frustrated and think I'm just being obtuse when I bring up those cases ^_^. I'm not sure I'd agree that `0usize` is any more or less fragile than a type on the variable declaration. One could also use `let mut counts: BTreeMap<_, usize> = BTreeMap::new()` or even `let mut counts = BTreeMap::<_, usize>::new()` I suppose.